# How can I get data from two tables and the second table shows row count

Tags: php

I want to show degrees and counts of the relevant degree id from the application table.

```
    SELECT * FROM degrees, applications 
where (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM applications WHERE degree_id = degrees.id AND `campus_id` =$campus 
AND DATE(`created_at`) = CURDATE() )  AS today, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM applications WHERE degree_id = degrees.id AND `campus_id` =$campus AND DATE(`created_at`) != CURDATE() )  AS previous, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM applications WHERE degree_id = degrees.id AND finalSubmission = 1 and response_status = 0 and `campus_id` =$campus)  AS pending, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM applications WHERE degree_id = degrees.id AND response_status = 1 and `campus_id` =$campus )  AS approved, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM applications WHERE degree_id = degrees.id AND response_status = 2 and `campus_id` =$campus )  AS rejected, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM applications WHERE degree_id = degrees.id AND finalSubmission = 1 and `campus_id` =$campus ) AS Total
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT degrees.id, degrees.title, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM applications WHERE degree_id = degrees.id AND `campus_id` =1 AND DATE(`created_at`) = CURDATE() )  AS today, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM applications WHERE degree_id = degrees.id AND `campus_id` =1 AND DATE(`created_at`) != CURDATE() )  AS previous, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM applications WHERE degree_id = degrees.id AND finalSubmission = 1 and response_status = 0 and `campus_id` =1 )  AS pending, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM applications WHERE degree_id = degrees.id AND response_status = 1 and `campus_id` =1 )  AS approved, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM applications WHERE degree_id = degrees.id AND response_status = 2 and `campus_id` =1 )  AS rejected, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM applications WHERE degree_id = degrees.id AND finalSubmission = 1 and `campus_id` =1 ) AS Total 
FROM degrees
```

Answer (score -2):

SELECT DISTINCT degrees.id, degrees.title,

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM applications
    WHERE degree_id = degrees.id AND `campus_id` =1 AND DATE(`created_at`) = CURDATE() )  AS today,

    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM applications
    WHERE degree_id = degrees.id AND `campus_id` =1 AND DATE(`created_at`) != CURDATE() )  AS previous,

    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM applications
    WHERE degree_id = degrees.id AND finalSubmission = 1 and response_status = 0 and `campus_id` =1 )  AS pending,

    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM applications
    WHERE degree_id = degrees.id AND response_status = 1 and `campus_id` =1 )  AS approved,

    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM applications
    WHERE degree_id = degrees.id AND response_status = 2 and `campus_id` =1 )  AS rejected,

    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM applications
    WHERE degree_id = degrees.id AND finalSubmission = 1 and `campus_id` =1 ) AS Total
```

FROM degrees